# testNG Eclipse plugin - results not displaying in testNG window

Tags: eclipse, testing, automated-tests, testng

I'm using the testNG plugin with Eclipse Indigo. The results of my tests have never been displayed in the testNG tab and I don't know why this is. I can access the results through the testng-results.xml file which is fine, I'm just curious as to why they are not displayed in the window as well? Any one else seen this before? I have both converted JUnit tests into testNG and started a testNG project from scratch, and the results window is blank in both scenarios.

Many thanks! :)

Comment: Do you may have a screenshot of the (empty) TestNG Tab?

Comment: I do, but I don't know how to attach it here?